# Using "similar in-spirit"

Tags: synonyms

Is this a correct use for the `in-spirit` synonym?

> Method-A is similar in-spiririt to method-B

Comment: I wouldn't use hyphens there, and I find it odd to refer to a *method* as having a spirit, but, those things aside, I see nothing wrong with using the expression as you have.

Comment: Unless this is some usage of language with which I am unfamiliar, which would be unlikely except in specialist fields or dialects that I haven't had much to do with, there shouldn't be a hyphen there. I'm also not sure what you mean by "the in-spirit synonym". Synonym of what?

Comment: Too many hyphens altogether. I would remove them all.